# Unable to close javafx application without closing the whole program

Tags: java, javafx, webview

I have an issue with an app i'm developing : Basically i have a javafx Application "MainApp" which shows a list of youtube videos (with a tableview) and a double-click on a row calls the play() method of the LecteurVideo class (code below). This launches a secondary app (in a new window) where the matching video will be displayed using a webview.

My Problem is when i close the secondary app (or secondary window) the window closes but the audio is still running. The only fix i found was to also close the MainApp when closing the video. But that's not what i want to do.

```
package proj;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.WindowEvent;
import proj.view.ShowResultsController;
import javafx.application.Platform;

public class LecteurVideo extends Application {    

    private String url; 

    public LecteurVideo(String url){
        this.url = url;

    }

    public void play(){
        launch();
    }

  public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    WebView webview = new WebView();
    webview.getEngine().load(url);
    webview.setPrefSize(640, 390);
    stage.setScene(new Scene(webview));
    stage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
            Platform.exit();
        }
        });
    stage.show();

  }

}
```

The `.setOnCloseRequest()` is a fix i found online while looking for a solution to my initial issue.

To summarize: what i want is to be able to close the Video Player window without closing the whole app BUT still shutting down the audio.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: That worked, i feel so dumb. I swear i spent an hour looking for an answer online and didn't see this once.  Thank you very much though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To stop the video, you likely need to unload the content from the web view. You can do this in the close handler for the window with

```
webView.getEngine().load(null);
```